# D3, Change the style of collapsible tree attribute

Tags: css, json, d3.js, orgchart

Im trying to do an OrgChart using d3 , i decided to use this tree [Collapsible tree](https://observablehq.com/@d3/collapsible-tree), so i want to remove the circles and apply my own style on the tree like adding borders to each title, change background color and so on...

Is there is any way i can do it ? if not do you suggest any other approach to create interactive organizational chart?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add borders and backgrounds to text, at least directly.

You can add some rectangles behind the text elements and style them as you want.

The issue with this approach is that you need to compute the text size for each element, so you size the rectangles properly.

You can make it a try and post your specific questions here.